# Convert W3C dateformat to milliseconds android

Tags: java, android, date, w3c

I have a `w3c date format` from server `2016-02-13T09:53:49.871Z` , I wanted it to convert to milliseconds for working with `Time since` concept

I get an error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: 2016-02-24T15:01:49+0530**

```
public  String formatTime(String timeFormat) throws Exception{

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        Date dateServer = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeFormat);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dateServer);
        long timeToFormat=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: W3C date format? That's ISO 8601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the milliseconds and `Z` is not recognised as a time zone - you can make it a literal `Z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
Date dateServer = fmt.parse(timeFormat);
```